# Why do Microsoft docs state "DO NOT use Enum.IsDefined for enum range checks."?

Tags: c#, .net

In a document Microsoft published [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/parameter-design) discussing parameter design conventions/best practices, it's stated:

> ❌ DO NOT use `Enum.IsDefined` for enum range checks.

Why do they discourage/advise against this and what's the preferred alternative?

Comment: One reason is that [it is expensive](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/9a50493f9f1125fda5e2212b9d6718bc7cdbc5c0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Type.Enum.cs#L20).

Comment: Questions of the ilk "what was Microsoft thinking when.." are off topic because we don't know, and it's a slim chance that an MS employee who does know will stop by and answer (SO is not a support forum for third party libraries). Microsoft's documentation is maintained [in a GitHub repository](https://github.com/dotnet/docs) - if you have an problem with it and feel it can be improved, you can raise an issue there and ask them to explain it. This is much more likely to reach someone who can answer "why did you write ..."